# How to use variable lag window functions?

Tags: sql, memory, window-functions, trino

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    userID,
    status, --'SUCCESS' or 'FAIL'
    date -- self explanatory 
   
);
INSERT INTO example
Values(123, 'SUCCESS', 20211010),
(123, 'SUCCESS', 20211011),
(123, 'SUCCESS', 20211028),
(123, 'FAIL', 20211029),
(123, 'SUCCESS', 20211105),
(123, 'SUCCESS', 20211110)
```

I am trying to utilize a lag or lead function to assess whether the current line is within a 2-week window of the previous 'SUCCESS'. Given the current data, I would expect a isWithin2WeeksofSuccessFlag to be as following:

```
123, 'SUCCESS', 20211010,0 --since it is the first instance
123, 'SUCCESS', 20211011,1
123, 'SUCCESS', 20211028,1
123, 'FAIL', 20211029, 1 --failed, but criteria is that it is within 2 weeks of last success, which it is
123, 'SUCCESS', 20211105, 1 --last success is 2 rows back, but it is within 2 weeks
123, 'SUCCESS', 20211128, 0 --outside of 2 weeks
```

I would initially think to do something like this:

```
Select userID, status, date, 
case when lag(status,1) over (partition by userid order by date asc) = 'SUCCESS' 
and date_add('day',-14, date) <= lag(date,1) over (partition by userid order by date asc)
then 1 end as isWithin2WeeksofSuccessFlag
from example
```

This would work if I didn't have the 'FAIL' line in there. To handle it, I could modify the lag to 2 (instead of 1), but what about if I have 2,3,4,n 'FAIL's in a row? I would need to lag by 3,4,5,n+1. The specific number of FAILs in between is variable. How do I handle this variability?

*NOTE* I am querying billions of rows. Efficiency isn't really a concern (since it is for analysis), but running into memory allocation errors **is**.Thus, endlessly adding more window functions would likely cause an automatic termination of the query due memory requirement being above node limit.

How should I handle this?

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Does this need to be done per user or just in date order without regard to users?  It's not clear how you wish to handle users.

Comment: @JonArmstrong it must be partitioned by user. In my example I have only one user, but the table has many. And the table should be ordered by user, date asc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach, also using window functions, with each "common table expression" handling one step at a time.

Note: The expected result in the question does not match the data in the question.  '20211128' doesn't exist in the actual data.  I used the example INSERT statement.

In the test case, I changed the column name to `xdate` to avoid any potential SQL reserved word issues.

The SQL:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
         SELECT *
              , SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY xdate) AS grp
           FROM example
     )
   , cte2 AS (
         SELECT *
              , MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'SUCCESS' THEN xdate END) OVER (PARTITION BY userID, grp) AS lastdate
           FROM cte1
     )
   , cte3 AS (
         SELECT *
              , CASE WHEN LAG(lastdate) OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY xdate) > (xdate - INTERVAL '2' WEEK) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isNear
           FROM cte2
     )
SELECT * FROM cte3
 ORDER BY userID, xdate
;
```

The result:

```
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
| userID | status  | xdate      | grp  | lastdate   | isNear |
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-10 |    1 | 2021-10-10 |      0 |
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-11 |    2 | 2021-10-11 |      1 |
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-28 |    3 | 2021-10-28 |      0 |
|    123 | FAIL    | 2021-10-29 |    3 | 2021-10-28 |      1 |
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-11-05 |    4 | 2021-11-05 |      1 |
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-11-10 |    5 | 2021-11-10 |      1 |
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
```

and with the data adjusted to match your expected result, plus a new user introduced, the result is this:

```
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
| userID | status  | xdate      | grp  | lastdate   | isNear |
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-10 |    1 | 2021-10-10 |      0 |
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-11 |    2 | 2021-10-11 |      1 |
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-28 |    3 | 2021-10-28 |      0 |
|    123 | FAIL    | 2021-10-29 |    3 | 2021-10-28 |      1 |
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-11-05 |    4 | 2021-11-05 |      1 |
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-11-28 |    5 | 2021-11-28 |      0 |
|    323 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-10 |    1 | 2021-10-10 |      0 |
|    323 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-11 |    2 | 2021-10-11 |      1 |
|    323 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-28 |    3 | 2021-10-28 |      0 |
|    323 | FAIL    | 2021-10-29 |    3 | 2021-10-28 |      1 |
|    323 | SUCCESS | 2021-11-05 |    4 | 2021-11-05 |      1 |
|    323 | SUCCESS | 2021-11-28 |    5 | 2021-11-28 |      0 |
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
```

Here's an extra test case, which might expose problems in some solutions:

```
INSERT INTO example VALUES
   (123, 'SUCCESS', '2021-10-11')
 , (123, 'FAIL'   , '2021-10-12')
 , (123, 'FAIL'   , '2021-10-13')
;
```

The result:

```
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
| userID | status  | xdate      | grp  | lastdate   | isNear |
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
|    123 | SUCCESS | 2021-10-11 |    1 | 2021-10-11 |      0 |
|    123 | FAIL    | 2021-10-12 |    1 | 2021-10-11 |      1 |
|    123 | FAIL    | 2021-10-13 |    1 | 2021-10-11 |      1 |
+--------+---------+------------+------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think calling the SUM (or the max) over the partition is exceeding the instantaneous memory limit. Is there a work around?

Comment: @Runeaway3 That sounds like a bug in the implementation. Did you try it with the restricted test case?  It's tough to imagine this common use of window functions exceeds limits.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS doesn't support window function filters you can `order by status desc` so 'SUCCESS' goes before 'FAIL'.

```
select userID, status, date, 
  case when lag(status,1) over (partition by userid order by status desc , date asc) = 'SUCCESS' 
        and dateadd(d, -14, date) <= lag(date,1) over (partition by userid order by status desc , date asc)
  then 1 end as isWithin2WeeksofSuccessFlag
from example
order by date
```

[Sql Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21ff3efd596e8046a9dfa6caab7e840c)

Comment: I am using Trino. Is this the DBMS?

Comment: Also I don't think this would work? If the FAIL is last, then it would compare against the very last success, and it would think it is outside of the 2 week window and ascribe a 0 to that row. In reality, it should be compared against the previous success based on the date.

Comment: @Runeaway3 You can just try on your system, or play with the fiddle in the answer.

Comment: I do not need to. Just with the example data I see that your query would not provide the right answer. The table must be partitioned user and then ordered by date asc.

Comment: @Runeaway3,  one can hardly benefit from the answers ignoring the code in the answer. Added the extended sample data provided by Jon Armstrong to my fiddle.

Comment: @Runeaway3 This answer works fine for the case provided.  But I think it may need a small adjustment to handle other cases, where more than one FAIL row is found after a SUCCESS.  It's why proper test cases are so important.  Given sufficient cases, I'm certain Serg would have easily made the adjustment.

Comment: Serg: Check this test case, added to your fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=402dd73c0555318790a0da573682e960